# Как мне выполнить файл .reg,который находиться в проекте как ресурс, через код c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

У меня в проекте лежит файл .reg по пути `project\regs\File.reg`
Как его можно выполнить через код c#.

Надеялся что получиться так `var file = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("project.regs.file.reg"))`

И выполнить его так

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "reg.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "import"+file;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Но результата 0. Надеюсь на вашу помощь)

Comment: А почему не переписать этот `.reg` в код? Это ведь ресурс, который вы сами зашиваете в свой проект, это файл не для пользователя, который лежит на диске и его каждый может подправить, это вы для себя сейчас делаете конкретный такой костыль, вопрос, зачем? Не, ну если так хотите, то вам надо сначала из ресурсов распаковать временно на диск файл, а потом вызвать примерно так `Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s file.reg");`, где `file.reg` - путь. Почему из ресурсов нельзя? А потому, что `regedit` требует путь, а не текст или еще что.

Comment: Реги слишком большие, их будет не удобно переписывать в код

Comment: Почему? Делаете массив, заносите туда путь, название переменной, значение, проходитесь циклом и добавляете, попутно накидывая проверки и прочее если надо, все, готово. Вам надо лишь, как и в `.reg` добавить новую строку. Вот "не удобно" это как по мне вот так вот копировать на диск, запускать левый процесс, не знать о результате, а затем еще и подчищать за собой следы удаляя временный `.reg`, вот это "не удобно", да.

Comment: Я просто в этом ещё новичок) допустим как это внести в реест [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]

"SmartScreenEnabled"="Off"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\PhishingFilter]

"EnabledV9"=dword:00000000

Comment: Пример для первого `Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer", "SmartScreenEnabled", "Off", RegistryValueKind.String);`, как и в файле, указываете путь, название значения, само значение, ну и тип.

Comment: А как их добавить, если из очень много. Просто не очень ещё понимаю циклы) буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: _Просто не очень ещё понимаю циклы_ - https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ

Comment: Благодарю вас за помощь!

Comment: Ну как как, берете и делаете массив со всеми значениями, допустим `var items = new[] { 1,2,3 };`, далее берете цикл, допустим `foreach` и проходитесь по массиву `foreach (var item in items){ ... }`, где `...` делаете что вам надо с конкретно одним значением. В качестве типа массива сделайте класс, который будет иметь эти 4 свойства (путь, название переменной, значение, тип), этот класс и используйте везде дальше.

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз)